# how to prevent a table being split at the end of page

Tags: tables

i'm doing a paper with a lot of tables which are done with the "tabular" environment or "longtable".
My question is how to prevent Latex to cut a table in 2 pieces when a table is at the end of the page ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't use longtable then.

Comment: `tabular` never splits, the only purpose of `longtable` is to allow page breaking, for tables longer than a page.